# Select MSI Features in WiX Bootstrapper

Tags: wpf, wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.6

I have already a MSI package (with several features) which I created via WiX. Now I also want to install the .NET framework as prerequisite if required. Therefore I created a Bootstrapper application based on WiX. In order to provide a nice looking user interface I created a Custom UI for the Bootstrapper with WPF. Anyway, now I want to create a page in my custom bootstrapper which allows the user to select the features from the MSI before I start with the installation. Here are my questions where I am stuck:

1. Is there a way to get the available features from the MSI which will be installed in the custom Bootstrapper application so that I can fill my user interface with the according "checkboxes"?
2. If I can list the available features for the installation (see question  #1), how can I apply the user selection from the Boostrapper User Interface to my MSI packages

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your bootstrapper code you could use the [Product Query Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installer-function-reference#product-query-functions) to open the MSI and determine the available features then display checkboxes for each.

To answer your second question you would just need to pass the feature names on the command line when launching your MSI to install. Comma separate your features and pass them to the [ADDLOCAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/addlocal) property.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but I don‘t think that wix offers access to functions like MsiOpenProduct. Or did I miss something here?

Comment: Sorry one more comment. I am still a bit lost. I played now a few hours with my installer but I am not really sure how to use the functionality you mention. I tried for example "Installer.OpenProduct("XXXX");" in the OnPlanComplete functionality but I always got - wrong parameter with an exception. I think I am using the wrong functionality or in a wrong context. Any help would be really great...

Comment: To be honest I don't know if WiX offers this natively in their bootstrapper. Maybe someone more familiar with it may respond.

My suggestion would need to use C++, C# or VBScript to interface with your generated MSI. I've done this plenty over the years. You can find lots of example code out there for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to break the MSI package out into several MSI micropackages along the feature lines.  Then conditionally install the MSI packages based on UI choices in the bootstrapper.